# NodeJs async does not work as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a node-js express-js app for my game .  I wanted to send a data to player. I have written a router for index. so When you post to index of my node js app. It well send the data to all players.

like

> POST http://localhost:3000/
>
> data : {
>
> "message" : "New Level
>
> available" }

at first request. The free beers appear instantly.

and I can see it is logging.

The problem is the second reguest hangs up. why?

```
 .post(function (req, res, next) {

            models.users.find({
                'uuid': recipient
            }, 'data type date', function (err, result) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //process a very large amount of kittens here.
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

                        //send kittens to all our users;
                    }
                } , 0);
            });
                res.send('free beers!'); 
            });
```

Comment: You're running a giant `for` loop that takes a long time starting when the timer fires.  The `res.send()` goes out and then the timer fires and the long `for` loop locks up the CPU for a long while.  What else are you expecting?

Comment: ammmmmm.....well....

Comment: I should add that your Javascript in node.js is single threaded.  So, once one a piece of Javascript starts running, it will run to completion before any other Javascript gets a chance to run.

Comment: oh. so I can make it multi threaded?

Comment: You can fire up another process to run some long running code.  node.js, by itself, doesn't run Javascript in multiple threads in the same process.

Comment: You can use the async library to run your code in parallel.

Comment: @RahatMahbub - No.  You can only run asynchronous operations in parallel (like async file I/O), not synchronous operations like a giant `for` loop.

Comment: I assumed his `for loop` was not really what he was actually doing.

Comment: The for loop was very large data  from my mongodb.

Comment: should I create a new instance of nodejs? I kinda lost about running another process

Comment: The `child_process` module can be used to run other processes.  Those other processes can be other node.js programs or anything else you want to run.

Comment: MongoDB queries/updates are done asynchronously so you can use the async library to take advantage of multiple threads. `child_process` is NOT ideal for this case.

Comment: Please provide some more actual code.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: I am guessing you are using mongodb. So you can load data as a stream. This will not eat up your memory for loading large amount of data. Also you won't need the synchronous for loop.